# Need help in customization of opencart

Tags: php, opencart, checkout

I need your help in figuring out how can I add a field in opencart's checkout page to show delivery charges currently I'm adding then via PHP coding to the total array. ANy Help could be appreciated thanks.

Current Result
[image: This is the current result that I am getting]

Desired Result
[image: Desired Result]

Comment: What shipping module(s) are you using? The shipping module should be adding that data in automatically.

Comment: I'm using no shipping module as the client has a requirement that his restaurant delivers to various postcodes in the UK, every postcode has different shipping charges. So instead of using a shipping module, I used custom PHP code to add the difference to the total according to the postcode. Now I want to display the shipping cost by the formula shipping=total-subtotal.

Comment: That sounds like a job for a shipping module. You could take the code you already have and integrate it into a copy of the most basic shipping module ('cash on delivery' is a pretty good skeleton to start from), or buy an extension on the marketplace: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_category_id=4&filter_search=postcode

If you want to carry on doing it the way you're doing it, you'll need to modify (at the very least) the checkout controller and the checkout template.

Comment: That sounds like a very good idea. ill take a look at it and let you know whether it fixed the issue or not.